# Callbacks for when a Fragment in a ViewPager is set as current page

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewpager, it has 5 fragments page. I can switch between each fragment by tapping a navigation button.

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is to refresh 1 of the page when entering it. (e.g. I'm in Page 1, when I tap button for Page 2, Page 2 will display and refresh.

However, I find out that the onResume method in the fragment is not called on this behavior. or any of the other lifecycle method.

I can't seem to find a way to do this. Is there any callbacks I can use for such scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Since you don't need any kind of caching, it's probably a good idea for you to use `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` so pages won't be loaded in background, and `onResume` will be called only when page is actually displayed.</strike>
**UPD:** Thanks, Yarh, for pointing out that `setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` doesn't work. Sorry for that.

If this doesn't work for you, use `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener)` - `onPageSelected(position)` method should help.

Comment: ok thanks. I'll probably look into the addOnPageChangeListener approach

Comment: thanks for this. I used addOnPageChangeListener, together with a method in my custom base fragment onDisplayed(). I get the current fragment from PagerAdapter when a page is selected and then call the onDisplayed() where I do the refresh for the page

Comment: viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0) has no effect, if it is less then 1, it will reset to 1. check implementation http://pastebin.com/Q6AMcctv

Answer (score 0):

use onTabSelected and onTabReSelected methods of navigation tabs to do your stuff

Comment: I'm not actually using navigation tab so I don't have those methods. I'm using a custom navigation buttons for my app

Comment: then you have to use pager.setOnPageChangeListener(listener) of View Pager