# How to update content in Fragment of ViewPager using AsyncTaskLoader?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I try to use `AsyncTaskLoader` in `Fragment` that is a child of `ViewPager`. Below a code of my `DayFragment`:

```
public class DayFragment extends Fragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<DayAdapter.DayItem[]> {

    private static final int CONTENT_LOADER = 0;

    private DayAdapter mAdapter = null;
    private int mWeekNumber = 1;
    private int mDayCode = 1;
    private Table.Timetable mTimetable;
    private RecyclerView mRVContent;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, container, false);
        mRVContent = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rvContent);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mainActivity);
        mRVContent.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new DayAdapter(getActivity());
        mRVContent.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //Initialize the cursor loader
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(CONTENT_LOADER, null, this).forceLoad();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<DayAdapter.DayItem[]> onCreateLoader(final int id, Bundle args) {

        if(CONTENT_LOADER == id) {
            return new ContentLoader(getContext(), mWeekNumber, mDayCode, mTimetable);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, DayAdapter.DayItem[] items) {

        if(CONTENT_LOADER == loader.getId()) {
            mAdapter.setIs24HourFormat(SettingsManager.is24HourFormat(getContext()));
            mAdapter.clear();

            for (DayAdapter.DayItem item : items) {
                mAdapter.add(item);
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (items.length == 0) {
                mRVContent.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_lesson_empty);
            } else {
                mRVContent.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {

    }

    private static final class ContentLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<DayAdapter.DayItem[]> {
        private final int mWeekNumber;
        private final int mDayCode;
        private final Table.Timetable mTimetable;

        public ContentLoader(Context context, final int weekNumber, final int dayCode,
                             Table.Timetable timetable) {
            super(context);
            mWeekNumber = weekNumber;
            mDayCode = dayCode;
            mTimetable = timetable;
        }

        @Override
        public DayAdapter.DayItem[] loadInBackground() {
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getContext());
            db.openReadable();
            List<Table.Lesson> lessons = db.findLessons(mDayCode, mWeekNumber, mTimetable.getId());
            DayAdapter.DayItem[] items = new DayAdapter.DayItem[lessons.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
                Table.Lesson lesson = lessons.get(i);

                Table.Subject subject = db.getSubject(lesson.getSubjectId());
                Table.Teacher teacher = db.getTeacher(lesson.getTeacherId());

                if (teacher == null) {
                    teacher = new Table.Teacher(""); //Empty name
                }

                items[i] = new DayAdapter.DayItem()
                        .setId(lesson.getId())
                        .setTitle(subject.getTitle())
                        .setSubtitle(teacher.getName()));
            }

            db.close();

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

**`PageAdapater`**

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public static final int PAGE_COUNT = 7;

    private int mWeekNumber;
    private final int[] mDayCodes;
    private final String[] mDays;
    private final DayFragment[] mFragments = new DayFragment[7];
    private Table.Timetable mTimetable;
    private boolean mIsRebuildMode = false;

    public PageAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm,
                       Table.Timetable timetable, final int weekNumber) {
        super(fm);
        //Initialize class members
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        DayFragment dayFragment;

        if (mFragments[position] == null) {
            dayFragment = new DayFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable(Keys.TIMETABLE, mTimetable);
            dayFragment.setArguments(args);
            dayFragment.setWeekNumber(mWeekNumber);
            dayFragment.setDayCode(mDayCodes[position]);
            mFragments[position]= dayFragment;
        } else {
            dayFragment = mFragments[position];
        }

        return dayFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {
        //do nothing here! no call to super.restoreState(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void setWeekNumber(final int weekNumber) {
        mWeekNumber = weekNumber;
        Arrays.fill(mFragments, null);
    }

    public void setIsRebuildMode(final boolean isRebuildMode) {
        mIsRebuildMode = isRebuildMode;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(final int position) {
        return mDays[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

        if(mIsRebuildMode) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }

        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't call `onLoadFinished` method. I checked `Log` output... `LoaderManager` calls `onCreateLoader` but it never calls `onLoadFinished` except first run (when app started and `ViewPager` shows a first page (`Fragment`)). It's all! After if I switch a page to a next and a next and return to a first page `LoaderManager` doesn't call `onLoadFinished` for the first page too. But it creates loader calling `onCreateLoader` and resets loader calling `onLoaderReset`. Is it a joke from Google?

Comment: Do you create new DayFragment every time in getItem() of your PagerAdapter? I made a very simplified test of your code and it's working, showing onLoadFinished. And, btw, no onLoaderReset was displayed in logs

Comment: No, fragment instances contain in list. Adapter returns already created fragment

Comment: If you change your adapter to FragmentPagerAdapter, is something changed? I cannot reproduce this (put my Fragment implementation, because don't have all your fields). And do you use support.v4 import everywhere?

Comment: Yeah, I use 23 revision. Unfortunately, I cannot use this adapter because then app cannot save its state correctly

Comment: I tried a lot of variants. And a single way that works: put loader initialisation in onCreateView and call `forceLoad` in `onStart`. But I did't like this way and I became use a simple `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1):

See fragment lifecycle. ViewPager don't re create fragment, just swipe them

-- Start ViewPager
: create
: createView
: start
: resume

not changed if you swipe fragments

--- sleep smartphone
: pause
: stop

--- wakeup smartphone
: start
: resume
: pause

--- Close ViewPager
: stop
: detach

Comment: Why is my `ViewPager` recreate a view every time?

Comment: I don't know You can check it by your self. Add logging in internal fragment and see lifecycle. I use ViewPager too and make this experience right now. The result you can see above

Comment: My adapter calls in fragments `onCreate` and `onCreateView` methods for all fragments when it hasn't the cached view, I checked output. Variable `mIsRebuildMode` has value `false`.

Comment: See ther how to recognise swipe fragments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062309/callbacks-for-when-a-fragment-in-a-viewpager-is-set-as-current-page#

Comment: Are u store all view in memory?

Comment: Ofcourse, one time when it started It call create, thats all

Comment: It's a bad idea for me. It can be reason of the memory overflow on old devices. I cache only 3 pages.

Comment: I use android.support.v4.view.ViewPager,  the developers store it. May be there is some parameters of caching I don't know

Comment: Of course it doesn't create view again. All ur fragments just cache in memory (default 3 fragment: current, previous and next).